# How to add button to navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

adding a button to navigation bar on first nib viewController and wanted to view this button to only on main screen not on any other screen 
i have worked out on it 
i made the button and added to subview of navigation bar 
on every button action i have put this

```
- (IBAction)forth:(id)sender {
    forthView *forthview = [[forthView alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:forthview animated:YES];
    btn.hidden = YES;
}
```

after this button hides but didnot show up when i got back to main screen
my code for viewdidload is here

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.title = @"My First View";

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 65, 30);
    [btn setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:btn];

    btn.hidden = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you hide the button so you need to unhide it again. here is the simple code to unhide the button:

```
btn.hidden = No
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad`is only called the first time your view is loaded. Add an `NSLog()`statement if you want to test when it gets called. Every time your view appers on screen `viewWillAppear`is called.
So you need to show the button in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that what you really want to be doing is adding a `UIBarButtonItem` to your main view controller's `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` property.  That way the button will have the correct appearance and show and hide as the view controller is displayed.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show"
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(onShowButtonPressed:)];
```